# can't import QtDeviceUtilities in QML

Tags: qt, qml, wifimanager

I can't import QtDeviceUtilities

`import QtDeviceUtilities.NetworkSettings 1.0`

I am referring to [Qt Documentation for QtDeviceUtilities](https://doc.qt.io/QtDeviceUtilities/qtdeviceutilities-wifitutorial.html#filtering-wifi-networks), What should I consider?

Comment: Please provide all relevant bits from that link in your question, and only leave the link as reference/source. Links can go dead and we want posts on Stackoverflow to remain useful in the future. Also please describe your problem in more detail. "I can't import" is not an accurate error description.

Comment: @MaxVollmer, That link is official documentation not a _tutorial_ as worded by OP, and the sole of the question is clear.

Comment: @MohammadKanan Admittedly I don't have domain knowledge here, but I don't need domain knowledge to judge that "I can't X" is not a proper error description. Also it's irrelevant how official a link is: The internet is volatile, links and websites change all the time. We have plenty of old posts linking to what was once official documentation that are now dead, invalid or have different content.

Comment: Closing this is a bad moderation decision. The question is clear.  And its a concise and accurate description. The code supplied doesn't work. OP wants to know why. Response below told them the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Qt for Device Creation is not covered with *LGPL*, its a commercial offering. In its documentation [Qt for Device Creation](https://doc.qt.io/QtForDeviceCreation/), shows green colored  *commercial* and black colored *LGPL* license schemes; All the modules require a commercial license.

Comment: Thanks for this. It had me beating my head against the wall trying to work it out. I'll have to find an alternative.